How to triangulate an abstract domain?
I am really curious about how to cut manifolds into simplex, but I want some additional properties. Here I assume all manifolds are two dimensional and X is triangulated means that there exists a complex which homomorphic to X.
I know all two dimensional manifold can be triangulated. And any smooth manifold can be smoothly triangulated. But I want stronger things. If I have a domain on a two manifold whose boundary is the image of a piecewise regular simple curve, here piecewise regular means except finite points, the curve is smooth and has nonzero derivatives. I want to cut it into simplex, which all edges are regular curves, how to do that?
Here is the problem I met: bad points on the boundary, which means at this point the curve is not smooth or its derivative vanishes. I want to use some simplex to cut them, and makes the rest an embedded submanifold , but I don’t know how to do that since I can’t use constant rank theorem to know the local behavior of that point, maybe it’s too bad that you can’t cut it away by a regular curve? I can’t imagine it but also I can’t prove it.
I wanna a strict proof, not only a sketch. Thanks.

The theorem saying that all two dimensional manifolds can be triangulated has many details in it that might be of interest to you. For example, there are relative versions of that theorem which are used as part of the proof of the absolute version. I will point you to Moise's book "Geometric topology in dimensions 2 and 3". I don't know that you'll find exactly what you want there, but maybe it will give you some ideas.

I'll add that perhaps one can also look up a careful exposition of Whitney's proof that smooth manifolds can be triangulated. I'll make a wild guess: there are steps in that proof as well which amount to relative versions; that might be exactly what you want.

@Lee Mosher Thanks, I will try to read them. But actually I have red Whitney’s proof of any smooth manifold can be triangulated on Luries notes about it, but I don’t find the things I want to solve my question. Maybe I can check them again since at the first time I don’t care the details.
